# Is it possible to build and use apache kylin with hbase2

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, kylin

In **apache kylin** distributions i can only see which are compatible with **hbase1.x.** 
My hbase version is 2.0 if anyone tested kylin with **hbase 2.x** please put your comment.

Thanks & Regards
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

We're testing Kylin on HBase 2.0 (HDP 3.0) recently. There are API changes in HBase so we couldn't directly run Kylin-HBase1.x on HBase 2.0. We will release an HBase2.x version when this work is done. Just keep tuned!

Comment: Kylin 2.5.0 has released, with the support for HDP 3.0 and CDH 6.0. You can download it from Kylin's downloade page.

Answer (score 0):

Tested **apache-kylin-2.5.0-bin-hadoop3** against **HBASE2.0** and it't working fine as expeted.